# RxJava: zip alternative

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a some 4 functions Which returns Observable of String

```
            Observable<String> id() {
                return Observable.just("1");
            }

            Observable<String> name() {
                return Observable.just("X");
            }

            Observable<String> place() {
                return Observable.just("Place1");
            }

            Observable<String> code() {
                return Observable.just("A100s");
            }
```

And I have an object, say `MyObject` which requires these 4 properties to create.

```
             MyObject m = new MyObject(id,name,place,code);
```

I have one more method which takes `MyObject` as input and returns some other Observalbe as follows

```
            Observable<String> finalResult(MyObject myObject) {
                    return Observable.just("Final result");
                }
```

To call `finalResult` I have to create `MyObject` by calling the first 4 methods , then pass `MyObject` to `finalResult`

Since all the first 4 methods are asynchronous, I'm using zip to get all the 4 values

```
             Observable.zip(id(), name(), place(), code(), new Function4<String, String, String, String, MyObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public MyObject apply(@NonNull String id, @NonNull String name, @NonNull String place, @NonNull String code) throws Exception {
                            MyObject m = new MyObject(id, name, place, code);
                            return m;
                        }
                    }).flatMap(new Function<MyObject, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<String> apply(@NonNull MyObject myObject) throws Exception {
                            return result(myObject);
                        }
                    });
```

Is there any alternative for `zip` for these kind of scenarios to reduce code length?

I saw `blockingGet` but I feel its not a good one to use for this. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: This seems fine to me. If you want to reduce code length then look at using lambda expressions.

Comment: So `zip` is the best recommended to handle this?

Comment: If you look at all the combining combining operators here http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining. Your strategy seems to be fine.

Comment: What I'm thinking is for methods like the first 4 , which are just returning `String` (like getters) If we dont make as Observables, 
That is instead of `Observable<String> id() { return Observable.just("1"); }` If we keep those methods just like 
`String id() {  return "1"; }` 
and do an Observable wrapper like `just` whenever needed it in an Observable chain. use normally otherwise.
This is not an Rx solution I'm telling, but design wise. Do you think it as a good approach? 
Or usually in an Rx application everything should be an Observable?